# Local Application Remote Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, architecture

This is outside my usual domain so please forgive my ignorance.

I am developing a Windows(7) plugin in C# for a local application that will query a database, returning the results to the application(simple). The issue is **people can work from home** so if I use a MS **SQL Express database** (as I usually would) it would be exposed on the internet and I have read an MS SQL server **exposed to the internet** is often compromised quickly.

I could install the database with the plugin, but I believe that would make managing the database, updates and troubleshooting a nightmare as there would be 15 separate deployments.

Can anyone **suggest approaches** to take to have a plugin for a **local application** that **queries a remote database** and is not a massive security liability or speak to the security of an internet accessible sql express delpoymeny?

Thanks
First post on stack overflow, I did search for answers prior to posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will want some type of web services layer between your database and the remote clients.

In this case you would have a web app that exposed certain service calls.  The calls should require some type of authentication and perform the necessary actions on the database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, if you can suggest any resources that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @db_newb: this can be as complicated or simple as you want.  The *easiest* way is to create a web application and use .ashx handlers.  Your client app would do an HTTP post to the .ashx file and get a response back.  JSON is good for this as it's more compact than XML.